# OkHttp3 Authenticator with RxJava

Tags: java, android, rx-java, okhttp

I have a TokenProvider with method:

```
public Observable<Token> authWithRefreshToken() {
    [...]
    return makeOAuth2Call(source);
}
```

The OkHttp's Authenticator implmentation looks like this:

```
@Override
public Request authenticate(Route route, Response response) throws IOException {

    Observable<Token> tokenObservable = tokenProvider.authWithRefreshToken();

    return response.request().newBuilder()
            .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + "HERE_I_HAVE_TO_SET_THE_TOKEN")
            .build();
}
```

Basically, my question is: how to do it right? Can I somehow receive Token synchronously? Of course I can change my OAuth API, but I am just curious.

Answer (score 1):

So after searching a while I found this:

```
@Override
public Request authenticate(Route route, Response response) throws IOException {

    Token tokenObservable = tokenProvider.authWithRefreshToken().toBlocking().first();

    return response.request().newBuilder()
            .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + tokenObservable.getRefresh_token())
            .build();
}
```

As the documentation of `toBlocking` says:

> Converts an Observable into a BlockingObservable (an Observable with blocking operators).

Comment: How much time will `tokenProvider.authWithRefreshToken` take to complete?

Comment: More or less the same as the original  request, which has to be replied.

Answer (score 0):

As you already have an interceptor for the original request, you can check the response in that interceptor and make a synchronous blocking call to refresh the token.

Then you can retry the original request.

Making a blocking call inside an Authenticator or Interceptor isn't a great idea but will probably usually work.  So something like

```
Response result = chain.proceed(requestWithOldToken);

if (result.code() == 401) {
  String newToken = refreshToken();
  Request requestWithNewToken = ...; 
  result = chain.proceed(requestWithOldToken);
}

return result;
```

I do something very similar in my project.

https://github.com/yschimke/oksocial/blob/2cdc38f1f6de255846a78b7c9f6747314b733a79/src/main/java/com/baulsupp/oksocial/authenticator/ServiceInterceptor.java#L49

Comment: I do have an interceptor with a token, I just want to handle the situation, when the token expired.

Comment: Ah yep, this needs to be done synchronously AFAIK.  e.g. https://github.com/yschimke/oksocial/blob/2cdc38f1f6de255846a78b7c9f6747314b733a79/src/main/java/com/baulsupp/oksocial/authenticator/ServiceInterceptor.java#L49

I missed, this, I'll update my answer

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you do this on the Rx layer, not in the OkHttp layer; this will block less threads and allow for f.e. retries on token retrieval failures.